# Combining two tables with keys that contain null

Tags: sql-server, join, null

I have two tables that I am joining

```
|id |profit|
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 1345 |
| 4 | 1454 |
| 5 | 1254 |
```

and another table

```
| id | x loss | y loss |
| 2  | 34312  | 4354   |
| 3  | 35614  | 4365   |
| 4  | 36615  | 4321   |
```

and combining the two, this would be the result I want

```
| id | profit | x loss | y loss |
| 1  | 1234   | Null   | Null   |
| 2  | 1345   | 34312  | 4354   |
| 3  | Null   | 35614  | 4365   |
| 4  | 1454   | 36615  | 4321   |
| 5  | 1254   | Null   | Null   |
```

The code that I used was

```
Select x.id, y.id, y.profit, x.xloss, x.yloss
from 
    (select id, SUM(xloss) as xloss, SUM(yloss) AS yloss
     from #SYSLOSSINC
     group by id) x 
  full outer join
    (Select id,sum(profit) as profit
     from #MTDPROFIT
     group by ProductCode) y 
  on x.id = y.id
```

I could not select just the id because of the error: *"ambiguous column name 'id'"*, and this is creating two columns with id as such

```
| id   | id   | Profit | xloss | yloss|
| Null | 1    | 1234   | Null  | Null |
| 2    | 2    | 1345   | 34312 | 4354 |
| 3    | Null | Null   | 35614 | 4365 |
| 4    | 4    | 1454   | 36615 | 4321 |
| Null | 5    | 1254   | Null  | Null |
```

How can I combine the id into one column so that null does not show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually simpler than you think. To get only one ID column, try:

`SELECT ISNULL(x.Id, y.Id) as Id,...`